# Calculate latitude and longitude from a center position

Tags: google-maps

Consider that I am having the following location points in google maps:
Latitude point: 112.
Longitude: 91.44 and
Radius: 5 (degrees).
So hoping that I can have a boundary level by using the above coordinates.

Now if I give a new latitude and longitude position, say:
latitude - 98 and
longitude - 12.3.

Is there any procedure to calculate whether the new coordinates (latitude - 98 & longitude - 12.3) lies inside the boundary..

If so can you explain that formula?

Thanks.

Comment: your title doesn't make sense, please reformulate..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this post

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

[Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points)